# Ошибка в классах

Tags: c++, классы

Помогите пожалуйста написать конструктор. Заранее спасибо. (вылезает ошибка "отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора Triangle::Triangle, соответствующие списку аргументов")

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Triangle 
{
private:
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
public:
    double Parties(double A, double B, double C) 
    {
        a = A;
        b = B;
        c = C;
    };

    void Perimetr()
    {
        double P = a + b + c;;
        cout << "Периметр: " << P << endl;
    }
    void Square()
    {
        double p = (a + b + c) / 2; 
        double S = sqrt(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c)); 
        cout << "Площадь: " << S << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите длины сторон треугольника";
    double a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Triangle one(a,b,c);
    one.Perimetr();
    one.Square();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если компилятор прямым текстом пишет, что не нашёл конструктор, быть может вы его забыли определить?)))

Answer (score 2):

Да откуда ж такая беспомощность...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Triangle
{
private:
    double a, b, c;
public:
    Triangle(double A, double B, double C):a(A),b(B),c(C){}
    double Perimetr()
    {
        return a + b + c;;
    }
    double Square()
    {
        double p = Perimetr()/2;
        return sqrt(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c));
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Введите длины сторон треугольника";
    double a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    Triangle one(a,b,c);
    cout << "Периметр: " << one.Perimetr() << endl;
    cout << "Площадь:  " << one.Square() << endl;;
}
```